# Postgres COPY with on conflict ignore - possible?

Tags: postgresql, copy, postgresql-12

I want to add on conflict ignore to the Postgres `copy` command.
I know I can copy the data to a table without unique index /primary key and then use insert with the `on conflict` syntax.
But I wanted to know if this is possible directly from `COPY`?

Answer (score 8):

No.  Maybe in some future version.  Now about the best you can do is use [file_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/file-fdw.html) to map the file in as a foreign table, and then INSERT INTO...SELECT...ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING